# Drupal: get page name from view.tpl

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I would like to get the current page title from a embedded view tpl.
I tried to get the $nid and arg(1), but nothing seems to work.

Using drupal 7

Comment: could you tell me what tpl is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use views_get_page_view() which returns a View object.
Then you can extract page name through following:
$views_page->name